# Validar max_size em um input type="file" com JS

Tags: json

Bom, estou tentando fazer a validação do max_size em js,
porém como não entendo muito, consegui apenas validar os formatos aceitos (jpg, png, etc...)

```
<input type="file" name="photo" id="photo" onchange="checkfile(this);" />



function checkfile(sender) {
    var validExts = new Array(".zip", ".rar", ".pdf", ".jpeg", ".jpg", ".png", ".tif", ".gif", ".JPG");
    var fileExt = sender.value;
    fileExt = fileExt.substring(fileExt.lastIndexOf('.'));
    if (validExts.indexOf(fileExt) < 0) {
      alert("Invalid file selected, valid files are of " +
               validExts.toString() + " types.");
      return false;
    }
    else return true;
}
```

Tenho um exemplo em mãos, mais não sei como colocar em conjunto com o checkthis

```
var uploadField = document.getElementById("file");

uploadField.onchange = function() {
    if(this.files[0].size > 307200){
       alert("File is too big!");
       this.value = "";
    };
};
```

Comment: começa modificando o  `file` para `photo` na variável `uploadeField`, e depois podes colar o teu exemplo normalmente numa tag `script` ou documento `js`. Diga o que aconteceu.

Comment: Não mudou nada, ele não faz a verificação do tamanho para retornar a mensagem "File is too big"

Comment: mostra como fizeste essa alteração.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faça assim:

```
<input type="file" name="photo" id="photo" onchange="verificar(this);" />
```

E podes reescrever a função dessa maneira, sem ter de recorrer ao evento `onchange` a toda hora. E para remover o ficheiro, basta atribuir `vazio` ao valor deste campo.

```
function verificar(ficheiro){
    var extensoes = [".zip", ".rar", ".pdf", ".jpeg", ".jpg", ".png", ".tif", ".gif"];
    var fnome = ficheiro.value;
    var extficheiro = fnome.substr(fnome.lastIndexOf('.'));
    if(extensoes.indexOf(extficheiro) >= 0){
        if(!(ficheiro.files[0].size > 307200)){
            alert('Pronto para carregar ficheiro');
            /* aqui, deve-se tambem validar o ficheiro no lado do servidor */
            return true;
        } else {
            alert('Ficheiro demasiado grande');
            // remover ficheiro
            ficheiro.value = "";
        }
    } else {
        alert('extensao inválida: ' + extficheiro);
        // remover ficheiro
        ficheiro.value = "";
    }
    return false;
}
```

> Em vez de verificar a extensão do ficheiro, o ideal seria verificar  o tipo `files[n].type`, assim consegue-se saber melhor de que tipo de ficheiro se trata, e isso pode ser feito de ambos os lados.

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado Edilson!

Comment: @FelipeSilva certo.

Comment: acho que não testei direito, o script não está funcionando, ele não aceita nenhum formatado, e eu coloquei o input e a função exatamente como você descreveu. Ele sempre dá mensagem de formato inválido

Comment: @FelipeSilva pois é, havia um erro ali na extensão, eu tinha suprimido o `.` e não voltei a coloca-lo, editei a resposta. Podes também colocar um `.` no inicio da extensão: `var extficheiro = '.' + ficheiro.value.split('.').pop()`, podes também remover os pontos todos de `var extensoes`.

Comment: deu certo Edilson, muito obrigado! Única coisa que não está aceitando de jeito nenhum é o formato .zip, não sei porque... O resto está tudo ok, todos os formatos configurados funcionando. Menos o .zip, tem algum motivo especifico, teoricamente se os outros estão aceitando, o .zip deveria aceitar também.

Comment: @FelipeSilva na verdade a condição de verificação deveria ser bem mais acentuada, e em vez de verificar a extensão, deveria verificar o tipo `MIME`, mas assim fica mais simples, então, coloque a condição `>= 0` porque o `.zip` possui índice `0` por ser o primeiro valor da array, faça assim: `extensoes.indexOf(extficheiro) >= 0`.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda, ficou perfeito! Parabéns, você manja muito!

Answer (score 1):

Insere abaixo do seu comparador de extensão:

```js
if (validExts.indexOf(fileExt) < 0) {
  alert("Invalid file selected, valid files are of " +
    validExts.toString() + " types.");
  return false;
}else if(sender.files[0].size > 307200){
  alert("File is too big!");
 this.value = "";
}
else return true;
```